# JSP's directory after Gradle building

Tags: java, spring-mvc, gradle, spring-boot

I wrote a simple application basen od Spring Boot, everything works fine, jsp files are mapped well, but if I want to build application (jar or war, tried both) by using Gradle - when I'm entering earlier properly mapped jsp i have typical "404 not found" error.

I've read people's solutions, but the popular one: move your jsps to "/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp" doesn't work for me unfortunetely.

If someone could give me a hint I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

for eclipse add the following code into `build.gradle` file create `webapp` directory

```
eclipse {
     wtp{
        contextPath = 'src/main/webapp/'   
     }
}
```